# When DOM gets ready in Backbone view

Tags: jquery, dom, backbone.js, marionette

I am developing an web app with backbone.js and marionette.js. Now actually we have

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

So of if I want to write code when the dom gets ready in Backbone, In which function should I write , initialize, render, onDOMRefresh.

Comment: Backbone's History module has a [`start()`](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) method, which will start your application. Don't forget to set your routes up first

Comment: If you append your template in render(), then write your document ready code after your template append.

Comment: @user10 I am not sticked to render but I want to know in which method I can write code which without backbone I was writing in document.ready.

Comment: There is nothing like that in backbone by default. It's upto you. If you use routers, then you'll switch between different views. So you should call things in render method of a view. If you are not using routers, then you can start initialize your backbone views inside document.ready.

Comment: Why don't you just keep this to know when the DOM is ready? Backbone requires jQuery so I don't see any problem.

Comment: You should continue using same `$( document ).ready` Backbone will just change the way you write other code, If you are using Backbone.Router, and defined router for your app Backbone.History.start() will start using those methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the onShow method.  When Marionette calls this method, the DOM elements are ready for you to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Marionette then this is how the methods you inquired about work:

`initialize` is called when a View first comes into being. It's a great location to handle any options you might be passing through from parent views, setup defaults, etc.

`onRender` is called everytime a "render" event is triggered in that view. A "render" event can be triggered the first time a view is instantiated as well as any time that view calls `.render()` on itself (you may do this when you want to update the content in this particular view). `onRender` may be called multiple times throughout the lifetime of a view.

`onShow` is called everytime a "show" event from a parent layout is triggered. A "show" event is triggered by a region within a layout calling `.show(subView)`. `onShow` will only be called once in the lifetime of a view.

`onDomRefresh` is called after a view is re-rendered and its new content is safely in the DOM.